# Is it possible to create unlisted (but public) boards in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

Is it possible to create a public Trello board, but only allow those with the link to view it (i.e., it does not show up in Search Engines)?

The need here is to have a somewhat private board (without sensitive information, but not applicable to the outside world), but reduce the friction from requiring every single stakeholder interested in the board to need to create an account and sign in every time.

This is similar to [YouTube's unlisted option](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177):

[image: YouTube Privacy Options]

Trello has the following [privacy options](http://help.trello.com/article/789-privacy):

[image: Trello Privacy Options]

Can you add a robots tag to a public board?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expose a read only view of a private board through [**trello.link**](https://trello.link/), a third party application built by a Trello Dev using the [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/) .

[image: Trello Link]

Although, the functionality is somewhat limited compared to a full board.

Comment: trello.link was shutdown Dec 1, 2017.